# Admin section logs out automatically in Magento

Tags: php, magento, logout, magento-1.6

I have just installed Magento CE 1.6.2 and the most annoying thing right now is that the admin interface automatically logs me out after maybe 3 minutes of inactivity. How do I fix this to either keep me logged in, or to increase the time before log out?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to increase your login time out then you have to change seesion lifetime time in admin, you can find this field in system->configuration->admin and select security tab and check session lifetime field here you can define your time.